# LINQ: Can't cast query result as List

Tags: vb.net, linq

I cannot cast the LINQ query below to a List using the .ToList() function.

It is not an option in Intellisense. If I force .ToList() at the end of the query, the entire query gets "red squigglied", and the error says that ToList is not a member of HRAReport.

I would prefer not to have this big nasty constructor, and have all the property setting done in the class, but I could not find a way to pass the hraRow and ddRow objects to the constructor.

I have two data table objects. The hraRow has most of the data, but I need to pull two columns from the ddRow object, hence the join.

I do not like the lambda version of Linq, which is why I'm using the verbose/query method.

I'm rusty - as you can tell - so please be gentle.

```
Dim results As List(Of HRAReport) = 
    From hraRow In dtHRA.AsEnumerable
    Join ddRow In dtDirectDeposit.AsEnumerable On hraRow.Field(Of String)("SS#") Equals ddRow.Field(Of String)("SS#")
    Select New HRAReport(hraRow.Field(Of String)("SS#"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Name - Last,First"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Benefit Plan Name"),
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("HRA Annual Election"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("HRA Benefit Start Date"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("HRA Benefit Term Date"),
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Address 1"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Address 2"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("City"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("State"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Zip Code"),
                         ddRow.Field(Of String)("Account #"), 
                         ddRow.Field(Of String)("ABA #"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Plan"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Debit Card"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Health Plan Code"),
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Email"), 
                         hraRow.Field(Of String)("Termination Date"))
```

Comment: You're trying to cast the resulting enumerable _to_ a `List`. You need to instead call `ToList()` at the end.

Comment: .ToList() at the end is not an available option in Intellisense and it results in a syntax error (red squiggly) if I "force it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `.ToList()` at the end, you are trying to cast an instance of `HRAReport` to a list. You should call it on the query itself:

```
Dim results As List(Of HRAReport) = (From hraRow In dtHRA.AsEnumerable
                                     Join ddRow In dtDirectDeposit.AsEnumerable On hraRow.Field(Of String)("SS#") Equals ddRow.Field(Of String)("SS#")
                                     Select New HRAReport(/*...omitted...*/)
                                    ).ToList();
```

Please note the extra pair of parenthesis.

(I hope this is the correct syntax in vb.net. I just thrown it into the telerik converter)

Comment: I'll try that, Marco. If that's what it is, I'm going to feel really silly.

Comment: That was the answer. Marco wins a gold star. Please don't downvote me for the incredibly stupid question. LOL.

Comment: We've all been there. No worries - glad I could help. Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer, if it solved your problem.